# Non-symmetric double-well energy levels

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, potential, schroedinger-equation, semiclassical

While going through Konishi's and Paffuti's book *Quantum Mechanics: A New Introduction*, I came upon an example that I see in many books on QM - the double well potential. The problem is then posed as that of a *symmetric* potential, usually in the form of $(x^2-a^2)^2$. The most common way to solve for the energy levels is the WKB method which brings about something like:

$$
\Delta E\propto e^{-\int_{-a}^{a}|p(x)|dx}.
$$

However, I was wondering what would happen if we were to pose the same problem but with a double well that isn't symmetric, which has its turning points in some points $a$ and $b$, being of the form $(x\pm a)^2(x\pm b)^2$ and how one would go about calculating the corresponding energy levels. From what I understand, the idea would be the same but the resulting integrals are no longer as simple and I have no idea what to do to circumvent this problem. The integrand would be (should be?) of the form:

$$
|p|=\sqrt{2E-\alpha(x-a)^2(x-b)^2}, \alpha\in \mathbb{R}
$$

for which I see no simple solution. In fact, the integrals of this problem don't seem to be simple in general and I'm probably missing something extremely obvious here but I seem to be stuck. Any tips in general will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In eq. (22) of https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0211096, we give a schematic approximation for the wave functions in an asymmetric double well, in terms of the energy difference and the tunneling matrix element.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but I don't understand how one arrives at that equation?

Comment: It seem that one can just shift the $x$-coordinate in OP's examples to get back to the symmetric potential.